# How to hide the uiview inside the collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have one `colelctionViewCell` with one label and one `UIView`. What I did is, in my custom collection view cell i have kept one method. That is : If user press the collection view cell.Then only color of that `UIView` will chnage Or else it will be in some other color.

But what i need is initially i need to hide my `view`. And for the first custom cell only my uiview should show. How to do that ??

```
@IBOutlet weak var ProductCatg: UILabel!                
@IBOutlet weak var highLightBar: UIView!

    override var selected: Bool {
        didSet {                                               
            if selected {
                highLightBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            } else {
                highLightBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            }                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just set the color of selected `Cell` then you can use `selectedBackgroundView` of `CollectionViewCell` like this.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(KCollectionViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! collectionViewCell
    let selectedview = UIView(frame: cell.contentView.bounds)
    selectedview.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedview
    return cell
}
```

**Note:** No need to add that `selected` code that you are using currently.